# How to use psutil.get_cpu_percent()?

Tags: python

How to exactly use the function get_cpu_percent()?

My code  is:

```
SDKTestSuite.DijSDK_CalculateFps(int(timeForFPS),int(index),cameraName)
cpuUsage = process.get_cpu_percent()
```

Here I am calling a Function called `SDKTestSuite.DijSDK_CalculateFps()` and I am calling `get_cpu_percent()` to get the CPU usage of this call. I am Calling this function for different inputs, The result is sometimes the CPU usage gives `0.0%` which is not expected.

So Am I using the `get_cpu_percent` in the correct manner? How to exactly use this `get_cpu_percent` function? Is there any interval parameters vary here?

In the actual definition of this function it just sleeps for the given interval and compares the CPU time, but how does it calculates my functionality call here?

Comment: Haven't you already asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018845/get-cpu-percent-function-is-getting-rounded-to-precision-1-why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all...
I got the solution for my query.

```
>>> p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
>>> # blocking
>>> p.get_cpu_percent(interval=1)
2.0
>>> # non-blocking (percentage since last call)
>>> p.get_cpu_percent(interval=0)
2.9
```

Here the interval value matters a lot. The final call will give the usage of cpu in percentage for my actual function call.

Comment: No it won't. You still don't understand what you're measuring, so you're reporting meaningless (or, at best, misleading) data. It gives the CPU usage of all programs on your computer running at the time you ask for it—which is after your function has already finished, and isn't even contributing to that CPU usage.

Comment: How will we get the cpu usage of a single process?

Answer (score 12):

If you read [the docs](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation#CPU), `psutil.cpu_percent` will:

> Return a float representing the current system-wide CPU utilization as a percentage… When interval is 0.0 or None compares system CPU times elapsed since last call or module import, returning immediately…

I'm pretty sure that's not what you want.

First, if you want to know the CPU usage *during a specific call*, you have to either (a) call it before and after the function, or (b) call it from another thread or process running in parallel with the call, and for the same time as the call (by passing an `interval`).

Second, if you want to know how much CPU time that call is using, as opposed to how much that call plus everything else being done by every program on your computer are using, you're not even calling the right function, so there's no way to get it to do what you want.

And there's nothing in `psutil` that's designed to do that. The whole point of `psutil` is that it provides information about your system, and about your program from the "outside" perspective. It doesn't know anything about what functions you ran when.

However, there are things that come with the stdlib that do things like that, like [`resource.getrusage`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html) or the [`cProfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) module. Without knowing exactly what you're trying to accomplish, it's hard to tell you exactly what to do, but maybe if you read those linked docs they'll give you some ideas.

Comment: I need to find out the CPU usage of the particular function call? How to get that?

Comment: @Bharathi: You mean the user-mode CPU time used by your process while running that function? If so, that's `resource.getrusage`, which I already gave you a link to. If not, what _do_ you mean?

Comment: I dont have much knowledge on user mode and all. My requirement is, I need to find out the cpu usage by that particular function call. Is it possible to get that by resource.getrusage

Comment: @Bharathi: If you're going to ignore the docs and repeat the same ambiguous question over and over, I can't promise that what `getrusage` gives will be what you want, because I don't actually know what you want. Trying to profile code without even knowing what the basic terms mean is pointless, and if you're not going to even try to learn, I can't help you.

Comment: I need to know the Percentage of cpu usage rather than any time info. So I think cProfile and resource.getrusage both wont fulfill my need.

Comment: U got my question now?

Comment: You want the average CPU % used by your process during that time? The peak? You want to add any cores used together, or repeat them separately? You want to count only CPU used by your process directly, or CPU used by the kernel on your behalf? For example, average CPU % used by all threads of your process directly as a fraction of all cores is (`ru_utime` after - `ru_utime` before) / (wall clock time after - wall clock time before). But if you want something different, the answer is different.

Comment: @Bharathi: Maybe if you explain what you're trying to use this _for_, someone can guess what exactly you want.

Comment: I dont want the average cpu. I would like to know the percentage of cpu usage by particular thread which calling that function.

Comment: @Bharathi: The percentage over a span of time is ambiguous. And if you don't want the average over that span of time, what _do_ you want? The peak? Something different? For example, if it runs for 2 seconds at 10% and 3 seconds at 20%, what number do you want to get back when that 5 seconds is over? And meanwhile, that's only _one_ of the four questions I asked, _all_ of which need answers. Again, if you don't know how to even explain what you want, can you try to explain _why_ you want it, so someone else can make an educated guess?

Comment: You cannot get the CPU usage of a particular function. Or better, you can by figuring out how long it takes for the function to return but I bet that's not what you're looking for. 
On the other hand you *can* get the CPU usage of a process (psutil.Process' get_cpu_times() and get_cpu_percent()) or their threads (psutil.Process.get_threads()).

Comment: @GiampaoloRodolà you are awesome. the way you try to teach that one should learn "what to ask" is beyond being helpful. thank you a lot.

Answer (score 3):

you need psutil

```
pip install psutil
```

then

```
import psutil,os
p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print(p.cpu_percent())
```

Answer (score 2):

`os.getpid` - this will return the PID of the program running this code. For example, when you run it on pythonw.exe, it will return PID of pythonw.exe.
Hence `p.get_cpu_percent` will return CPU usage of that process.

if you want system wide CPU, `psutil.cpu_percent` can do the job.

Hope this helps, Cheers!