How to get correct CPU usage like in task manager using Python?
I am using psutil but the values I get is between 0 and 2% whereas the task manager is showing values way above that from 8 to 40% CPU usage. Am I missing something?
import sys
import psutil  # To get CPU and RAM usage
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class CircularProgressBar(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, label="CPU", color=QtGui.QColor(255, 140, 0), parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.label = label
        self.color = color
        self.value = 0
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_value)
        self.timer.start(1000)  # Update every second

    def update_value(self):
        # Make sure the first call was done before to avoid 0.0 initial value
        if not hasattr(self, 'initial_call_done'):
            psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)  # Establish baseline
            self.initial_call_done = True

        # Get CPU usage with a non-zero interval
        self.value = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        width = self.width()
        height = self.height()
        side = min(width, height)

        # Create a QPainter instance
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

        # Draw the background circle
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(10, 10, side - 20, side - 20)
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.gray, 10)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawArc(rect, 0, 360 * 16)

        # Draw the progress arc
        pen.setColor(self.color)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        angle = int(self.value * 360 / 100) * 16
        painter.drawArc(rect, 90 * 16, -angle)

        # Draw the label and percentage text
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.white)
        painter.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", side // 10))
        painter.drawText(rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, f"{self.label}\n{self.value:.0f}%")

        painter.end()

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("Resource Monitor")

    # Create a central widget and layout
    central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central_widget)

    # Create and add progress bars
    cpu_bar = CircularProgressBar("CPU", QtGui.QColor(255, 140, 0))
    cpu_bar.setMinimumSize(200, 200)
    
    layout.addWidget(cpu_bar)
    window.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    window.resize(600, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Maybe make the second call with interval=0 to compute cpu usage since the first call?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090379/how-to-use-psutil-get-cpu-percent

I don't know about your specific issue, but you should not use the interval argument in the main thread, as it's blocking (which should always be avoided in GUI). You may consider moving that polling to a separate QThread, call cpu_percent() at smaller intervals (eg. 100-200ms) and without the interval argument, then emit a signal at larger intervals with an average of the latest results (for instance, every 10 polls).

Correction: if you use a separate thread, you may use the blocking mode (specifying an interval). With interval=None, you may do it in the main thread, but you should collect more values for statistical accuracy.
